# "undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, Complex<int>&)" for template Complex<T>

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend-function

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

template<typename T>
class Complex
{
    T real, img;
public:
    Complex():real(0), img(0){}
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex& c1);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Complex& c1);
    Complex operator+(Complex& c1);
};

template<typename T>
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex<T>& c1)
{
    cout<<"Real: ";
    input>>c1.real;
    cout<<"Imag: ";
    input>>c1.img;
    return input;
}

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Complex<T>& c1)
{
    output<<c1.real<<"+"<<c1.img<<"i";
    return output;
}

template<typename T>
Complex<T> Complex<T>::operator+(Complex<T>& c1)
{
    Complex temp;
    temp.real = this->real + c1.real;
    temp.img = this->img + c1.img;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Complex<int> cmp1;
    cin>>cmp1;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is at `cin>>cmp1` which is `undefined reference to 'operator>>(std::istream&, Complex<int>&)'`. But I can't find anything wrong in my code.

The code works if I make complex a non-template class which uses double and remove all template-related code, so the definition of `operator>>()`  is essentially correct.

What changes when I make `Complex` a template?

Comment: I removed the outpour of your desperation and added a few relevant tags. I didn't know the answer here, so the problem  is not trivial, from my perspective. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Friend functions are not members so they aren't implicitly templates. Declaration there suggests existence of non-template operator for instantiated type `Complex<int>`.
You may use

```
template<typename U> 
friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex<U>& c1);

template<typename U> 
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Complex<U>& c1);
```

Comment: While this is strange (because normally the class template name inside a class template definition refers to the respective instantiation) I would expect a different error message, namely "non-friend operator<<() cannot access private member of Complex<int>".  Because that's what a friend declaration does, provide  access.  But I guess the template operator>> is never instantiated, because language rules, so we end up with a linker error instead. Ugly.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think it's because ADL is possible in some cases but not in  global namespace. Except it isn't here unless we have a buggy compiler which allows ADL in global namespace, e.g. MSVC.  Declaring this operator as non-template friend supposes that we can declare `friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex<int>& c1);` later on  and it would be usable with `Complex<int>`, can't we?

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that currently the overloaded friend functions are **ordinary functions**. If you want to make them as function templates instead then you need to change the **friend declarations** inside the class to as shown below.

To be more formal, in your original code `operator<<` and `operator>>` for class template `Complex<>` are not  function templates, but “ordinary” functions *instantiated with the class template if needed*. That is, they are **templated entities**.

There are 2 ways to **solve** the problem, both of which are given below.

##### Solution 1

```
template<typename T>
class Complex
{
    //other members as before
    
    //friend declarations
    template<typename U>
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex<U>& c1);
    template<typename V>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Complex<V>& c1);
    
    //other members as before
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Tia5zyZ8P)

##### Solution 2

```
//forward declarations
template<typename T>
class Complex;
template<typename U>
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex<U>& c1);

template<typename V>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output,const Complex<V>& c1);

template<typename T>
class Complex
{
    T real, img;
public:
    Complex():real(0), img(0){}
    
    //friend declarations
    
    friend istream& operator>> <T>(istream& input, Complex<T>& c1);
    
    friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream& output,const Complex<T>& c1);
    
    Complex operator+(Complex& c1);
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/eXOU8Xmrh)

Comment: So, the original friend declaration basically refers to an unrelated, non-template class `Complex`?? Would such a class with the same name as a class template be permitted at all? Once more those arcane C++ rules, a quagmire.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I have added a 2nd solution to the problem in my edited answer. Check out both the solutions. Now coming back to your question. Technically, in the original code of OP `operator<<` and `operator>>` for class template `Complex<>` are not  function templates, but  “ordinary” functions *instantiated with the class template if needed*. That is, they are **templated entities**.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica `Complex` refers to `Complex<T>`. Actually it would expect an instance which would use related `Complex<T>`argument. E.g. if you had instantiate  `Complex<double>` , You have to define a standalone function (non-template) with `Complex<double>` argument to  satisfy linker.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica `Complex` is actually `Complex<T>` because of **Injected class names**. You can refer to [Injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) for more about the topic.